# Dudas Desarrollo en capas en MVC usando EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en capas(estoy usando 4 capas)

[image: Desarrollo capas]

Como ven en la capa de datos uso EF(database First) cree una capa Entities en donde moví las clases poco(.tt) generadas por EF hasta aquí no hay problema , el problema resulta cuando quiero agregar una vista o controlador en mi capa web MVC no me aparece ningún Data Context Class
[image: Data Context]

Creería que es porque el Data context se encuentra en la capa de datos donde tengo mi modelo y como en mi capa Web solo agrego como referencia mi capa de negocios y Entities.

La duda es, Entonces es necesario que en mi capa web agregue como referencia mi capa de datos(al agregar como referencia si me aparece el Data Context)

He tratado de hacerlo de la siguiente manera

EF me ha creado una clase entidad de la siguiente manera

```
    public partial class Categoria
{

    public Categoria()
    {
        this.Articulo = new HashSet<Articulo>();
    }

    public int CatId { get; set; }
    public string CatNombre { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Articulo> Articulo { get; set; }
}
```

yo he pensado crear en la capa Entities una clase Modelo de la siguiente manera

```
    public  class ModeloCategoria
{
    public int CatId { get; set; }
    public string CatNombre { get; set; }
}
```

Y en mi capa datos hago lo siguiente para listar mis categorias

```
 public class CategoriaDAL
{
    public  List<ModeloCategoria> ListarCategorias()
    {
        using (ProductosEntities bd = new ProductosEntities())
        {
            return bd.Categoria.Select(MapearAplicacion).ToList();

        }
    }


    //metodo para covertir modelo a clase ef
    private ModeloCategoria MapearAplicacion(Categoria cat)
    {
        return new ModeloCategoria()
        {
            CatId = cat.CatId,
            CatNombre = cat.CatNombre
        };
    }

    private Categoria MapearBD(ModeloCategoria modelo)
    {
        return new Categoria()
        {
            CatId = modelo.CatId,
            CatNombre = modelo.CatNombre
        };
    }
}
```

en mi capa de negocios hago lo siguiente

```
 public class CategoriaBL
{

    public static List<ModeloCategoria> ListarCategorias()
    {
        CategoriaDAL cat = new CategoriaDAL();
        return cat.ListarCategorias();
    }



    private static Categoria MapearBD(ModeloCategoria modelo)
    {
        return new Categoria()
        {
            CatId = modelo.CatId,
            CatNombre = modelo.CatNombre
        };
    }

    private static ModeloCategoria MapearAplicacion(Categoria cat)
    {
        return new ModeloCategoria()
        {
            CatId = cat.CatId,
            CatNombre = cat.CatNombre
        };
    }

}
```

Pero me surge la duda que los metodos para convertir el modelo a las clases entidades lo tengo que implementar en la capa de negocios y en la capa de datos(no se si sea la mejor opcion)

Por ultimo en mi controlador tengo lo siguiente

```
    public ActionResult Index()
{
    var cat = CategoriaBL.ListarCategorias();
    return View(cat);
}
```

No se si sea la mejor manera de hacerlo.

Comment: Sí, es necesario agregar la referencia, de lo contrario la capa web no sabría de la existencia de la capa de datos.Como información adicional: en la programación por capas, en un nivel más avanzado, se utilizan interfaces como referencias en lugar de clases concretas, esto con el propósito de lograr un desacomplamiento entre las capas.

Comment: Entonces en sí no sería programación en capas ya que la capa de datos no tendría que tener referencia con la capa web(en Windows form lo hago sin problema siempre usando ef)

Comment: Estás utilizando scaffolding de MVC, intuyo que el 5, el cual **no tiene en cuenta una arquitectura en capas**, ya que está orientado a manejar los datos directamente desde la capa de presentación, por lo que estás cargando a esa capa de una responsabilidad que no es la suya. Y si realmente la funcionalidad que quieres realizar es el CRUD de una tabla te vas a encontrar con que tampoco tienes lógica de negocio, por lo que tampoco tiene mucho sentido esta capa, ya que se va a dedicar a ser una mera interfaz. Realmente ¿qué quieres hacer? te iremos ayudando

Comment: Si uso MVC 5 lo que quiero hacer es un crud con algunas validaciones por eso creo mi capa de negocios. He agregado codigo de una idea de como he pensado realizarlo pero no se si sea la mejor opcion